# Use variable for string substution in makefile

Tags: make

I've this really simple make file:

```
run:
        test -f ./bin/alfred-proxy || wget "http://localhost:8081/1.0.26/my-binary-1.0.26.tar.gz
" -O /tmp/my-binary.tar.gz && tar xfvz /tmp/my-binary.tar.gz
        go build && ./my-awesome-binary
```

I want to move the version `1.0.26` to a variable so that I can change it easily in future and it's not part of the long command.  How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5):

Variables in makefiles are pretty straight forward:

```
version = 1.0.26
run:
        test -f ./bin/alfred-proxy || wget "http://localhost:8081/$(version)/my-binary-$(version).tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, I was defining it under `run:` block and hence the issue.